# Where to begin with Smartphone Web Development?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, smartphone

Ha all,

So I've been taksed with developing a smartphone website for our property portal and first thing I did was see what lessons others had to tell online but I've found very little.

I'm not building an app, I'm building a website and I'm looking for do's and don't with regards to html, css, widths/heights approaches, javascript (is jquery going to play nice on all platforms?) and anything else that relvant to this kind of platform.

Looking around at others I like http://mobile.whistlerblackcomb.com/ very much.

Regards,
Denis

Comment: What phones do you need to be compatible with?

Comment: Thats not spec for me. We have a wap site and thats not being replace rather we want something in between our live site for wap and the web which iphones, driods, palm pres etc can get as the load from the main site is high and the wap functionality is low.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

While most of the text below still applies, I would now say that [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) does a great job of providing a well-designed and usable set of UI components, while also alleviating a lot of the device testing and detection issues that I've used WURFL for in the past. It's still in beta, but seems to be working pretty well. I recommend checking it out.

---

The two most important issues to consider when getting started are:

1) Device detection

2) Mobile UI design

For issue number 1, I strongly recommend looking at the WURFL device dataset:

http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/

Using this, you can retrieve (some) capabilities of devices that are accessing your site, using their User Agent string. Testing mobile web apps is kind of like browser testing from hell--there are so many different combinations of devices and browsers, that it's a difficult task. If you can focus on developing one or two versions for fairly capable phones, say:

1) minimum 300px width with claimed "web" support and a touch screen
2) The same as above, but without a touch screen

you can create a very usable site that will work for most "smartphones," or "app phones" as [David Pogue](http://www.nytimes.com/2009/11/05/technology/personaltech/05pogue.html?_r=2) has more accurately named them. For the actual testing, you can try:

1) Making a list of all of your friends and what kind of phones they have
2) Going to a phone store and using those phones to test your site

and, regardless of what you do, you'll have to be agile when you receive the inevitable user feedback about broken/slow content on their device.

Regarding UI design, there are a couple of issues. The simplest one is nice looking CSS. Here, just look at some mobile sites you like and steal their CSS. Once you've done this, you're basically doing regular old web development, just on a small screen. ul's will become nice iPhone-y tables, etc.

The bigger problem is mobile web usability. In a lot of ways, we're in a 90s-web situation with mobile web development. What I mean is that we working without well-established design patterns. This makes doing mobile web development really fun, but it also means that you have to be ready to adjust your ugly/broken UI as better ideas evolve. One current example are the global nav/breadcrumbs you see on a lot of mobile sites. A surprising number of folks out there are trying to mimic the behavior of native iPhone apps by providing a persistent navigation tool (back button) within the mobile app. While this is kind of pretty, it has a few problems:

1) It is redundant, given that the browser comes with a back button that users are very familiar with. The reason these global navs exist in native apps is that they don't come with a free navigation tool.

2) The web is great. You can enter, leave and re-enter "apps" at any point in their structure. By assuming that a user takes a linear path through your app, you are decreasing its webiness, making it a lot more crude relative to the rest of the web.

3) It breaks. Either you can get in a situation where the app nav and the browser nav point in opposite directions (hitting the back button in your app steps forward through the app history), or you fake a back button with javascript, which breaks if they don't start at the beginning of an app (emailed link, bookmark), or you set up sessions, which can be a big pain just to replicate what you get from the browser for free. Sessions are also vulnerable to brokenness (emailed links, bookmarks), and you're really not gaining much.

I guess my main points here are:

1) Don't forget you're on the web. The web is cool, browsers are cool, make use of that.

2) Don't be afraid to play around. There aren't many well-established patterns here, so you may have to try out some of your own.

Comment: Also, if you are planing on using mysql as your database, Tera-WURFL (http://www.tera-wurfl.com/) gives a really nice performance boost compared to vanilla xml wurfl.

Answer (score 1):

A List Apart can get you started:
["Put Your Content in My Pocket"](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/putyourcontentinmypocket/) by CRAIG HOCKENBERRY

Answer (score 0):

With modern smartphones there's actually no difference between developing a conventional webpage and a dedicated website.

But you could try the emulators that the major players like Apple, RIM, Motorola and Nokia provides to see how they look.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking a look at some other mobile sites. I posted a few below.

- m.reddit.com
- diggriver.com
- mobile.washingtonpost.com

Answer (score 0):

Since modern mobile browsers work quite much like desktop browsers, the old adage of "minify JS and CSS, optimize images" should be your primary concern, as bandwidth is more valuable on mobile devices.

In addition, consider following:

- Think if you need all your images, and if they are too large for small screens. Consider removing or reducing the size of large images.
- Check your JavaScript - Will your site work without it? It may be beneficial to disable parts of it, as it may easily reduce speed on mobile browsers
- You can often get by simply by including specialized CSS styles tailored for small screen devices in your main site

You might also find this helpful: [Why your mobile site probably sucks](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/07/23/why-your-mobile-site-probably-sucks/)

Answer (score 0):

Mobile sites are often used on regular phones, and often go to m.example.com instead of  www.example.com.  These sites have little/no javascript or css compatibility.  When you ask about mobile sites, keep in mind that there are two types of mobile sites.

Modern smartphone are supposed to handle browsers the same as a full fledged browser, but they are not.  In fact, the iPhone lives in a fantasy world and will report a window width of over 900 pixels!

There are tricks that you can do for a smartphone.  A touchscreen has no use for the :hover pseudo-class.  This can be a problem for menus that require hovering.  You can design around this.   How? you ask...

Apple looks at a new meta tag   (do a google search on it) and other smartphone browsers look at this as well.  With this, you can force the smartphone to report it actual screen size in pixels, and not it's pre-programmed fantasy size.

Now that you have done this, you can use css conditional statements,

@media only all and (max-width:600px){

```
CSS RULES THAT ONLY APPLY IF THE SCREEN WIDTH IS <600 PIXELS
}
```

I've used this to block `<div>`s that cluttered up a mobile device screen: lightbox, for example.  I also used this to modify image widths, so they fit on the device better.  Why did I choose 600 px?  I felt that many of the newer "netbooks" should be lumped in here as well.

I hope this helps.

--Dave

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do development specifically for an iPhone or iTouch use thise conditional statement.

```
[if SafMob] @import url(iphone.css);
```

Here is an article about building sites for mobile.
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/pocket/

Answer (score 0):

Meagan Fisher's talk on [Designing Effective Mobile Interfaces](http://events.carsonified.com/fowd/2009/london/mp3s/meagan-fisher/videos) provides a good overview. She recommends the book "Mobile Web Design" by Cameron Moll. Technology wise, I'd start by getting familiar with XHTML Mobile Profile if you're not already.

As far as design goes, think thin. Snag a book with nice typography and see if you can duplicate the page layout with CSS. "Elements of Typographic Style Applied to the Web" is a good starting point for that. Phone websites are about scrolling, not complex navigation. Rhythm and spacing are important. Keep images small and your text high contrast, and you'll end up with something that loads fast and looks good.

Answer (score 0):

There is also this threeparter, "Mobile Web Design" by Cameron Moll:

[State of the Mobile Web](http://www.cameronmoll.com/archives/000415.html)
[Methods to the Madness](http://www.cameronmoll.com/archives/000428.html)
[Tips & Techniques](http://www.cameronmoll.com/archives/000577.html)

The series is from 2005, but many of the info is still relevant. The last part "Tips & Techniques" also lists a lot of other resources on mobile web development.